# Material and Textures looks Completely different in Unity

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

I'm modelling a Curved Gate/Door in Blender, rverything looks fine in Blender, but in Unity, it looks dull and stretched.

I even tried to tweak the material's settings (tiling is uniform 1, 1) but I couldn't get the desired result.

Here are some pics:
https://ibb.co/F3fZ8GG

https://ibb.co/kx9VCTJ

https://ibb.co/ThjyG6K

Comment: Did you Apply (Ctrl A) Rot and Scale on every object before exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be the reason that josh sanfelici mentioned.
Also check this https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-blender-2-8-eevee-shaders-still-be-used-with-unity.645271/, that someone mentioned about using HDPR. I am also looking for the answer.